# Basic Login Not Working When Trying To Pull Information From a Class

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to make just a basic login, where I use the username and password that I create within the Info class. It runs but the print statements don't. I'm not really sure how to improve/fix it.

class Info:
def **init**(self, first, last, username, password):
self.first = first
self.last = last
self.username = first + "." + last
self.password = first + "_" + last + "123"

inf_1 = Info("Bob", "Scott", "", "")

class Login:
def **init**(self, username, password):
super().**init**(self, username, password)
def check(self):
if (self.username == log_name and self.password == log_pass):
print("Login successful")
else:
print("Unsuccessful Login")

log_name = input("Enter your user Username: ")
log_pass = input("Enter Password: ")

Comment: Hi there, please ensure you question meets the SO guidelines for others to reproduce. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to improve your question.

Comment: Not reproducible